# tkinter .insert adds lines to two listboxes at once

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a tkinter GUI and I have two list boxes that are supposed to have the same single line of text inserted into them upon initialization. The listboxes have separate names, but each time I run .insert for either of the listboxes, both of them get the line added to them and I can't figure out why. The same thing happens when they get their unique data. Here is example code copied from my program:

```
names = ["+ Add New Condition"]
bcList_lsb = tk.Listbox(bc_frm,listvariable=names)
bcList_lsb.grid(row = 1, column =1)
bcList_lsb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',command = bcLbClick)
bcList_lsb.insert("end",names[0])

solNames = ["+ Add New Condition"]
solBcList_lsb = tk.Listbox(solBc_frm,listvariable = solNames)
solBcList_lsb.grid(row = 1, column =1)
solBcList_lsb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',command = solBcLbClick)
solBcList_lsb.insert("end",solNames[0])
```

The setup for the two frames is identical except for their names and their commands.
Here is what it looks like in the GUI upon initialization:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in effect given both listboxes the same `listvariable` which forces them to be in sync. When you specify the `listvariable` option, the string representation of what you give it becomes an internal variable name. Both widgets end up with a variable named `"['+ Add New Condition']"` (eg: `str(["+ Add New Condition"])`) which means they are the same variable internally.